# Global Movement Estimation of squence of images in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, video-processing

I need to find a  C++ library to find the global movement estimation for a project of super resolution of medical images.  But I'm not aware of any of them.  Does anyone know a library that could help me do this?  I've heard of OpenCV but haven't found anything, maybe I wasn't looking at the right thing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good starting point:

http://www.cvpapers.com/rr.html

although I'm surprised to not see VXL on the list:

http://vxl.sourceforge.net

Have fun!